# I hava an error with spinner.setAdpter (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin android 
I have Spinner , When I use the `setAdapter` function I get this error

```
Error 3 'Android.Widget.Spinner' does not contain a definition for 'setAdepter' and no extension method 'setAdepter' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Widget.Spinner' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is my code

```xamarin
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


namespace FSF
{
    [Activity(Label = "Request")]
    public class RequestHolidayActivity : Activity
    {
        Spinner spinner_holidayType;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RequestHoliday);

             spinner_holidayType = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.RequestHoliday_spinner_holidayT);


             var items = new List<string>() { "first", "second", "third", "forth" };
             var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);


               spinner_holidayType.setAdepter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve it , but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is not SetAdapter method. Instead use the Adapter property and change your code to: `spinner_holydayType.Adapter = adapter;`

Comment: It would be great if mark my answer as solution to you problem.

Comment: I have only 12 reputation , So I can't mark your answer . Thanks .